# How to change Tax-class for 6000 products

Tags: magento-1.9, tax-class

I've about 6000 products with empty TAX-CLASS, what is the best approach to correct it to a proper TAX-CLASS. All the products will get the same tax-class insteed of an empty one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Catalog->Manage Products.

Select All Products and select action is "Update attributes" then submit

In attributes tab you see "Tax Class", select tax class then save it.

Comment: In my Update Attribute Tax class missing inside attribute tab, how to make visible? @Prashant Valanda

Comment: If you are not seeing the "Tax Class" option in the list try to filter your selection by Attribute set. There is a good chance that some products don't have the tax class attribute assigned.

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach:

1. Get the entire collection of products
2. In a `foreach` loop load the instance of product and set the tax class.

You can take a look in `tax_class` table to see the corresponding id for each tax class.

```
   <?php
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
Mage::app();

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($products as $product) {
    //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
    try{
        if($product->getTaxClassId() == 0){
            $product->setTaxClassId(2); //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            $product->save();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Save this script under your root instalation of magento, in a `php` file and run it

Comment: For your information, loading a product in a loop of a product collection is a bad practice. Your product is already loaded in the collection so you can use directly the `$product` var from your foreach ;)

Answer (score 0):

The script from Alex will ruin every product when it already has a tax class or is declared as shipping. Don't run it this way! Use some filters while grabbing your collection or use an if statement in the loop.

Comment: Ok.. I have added a validation in loop, to see if the product has "none" tax class. Thanks for the observation

Comment: I think this is a good answer now, gave you an up for this one.